# C++11 for loop in a Template Function

Tags: c++, c++11

I am trying to write a function which would Print Data on the console. The function is to be templated as it should accept different types of Data.

The code is as shown below:

```
template<typename DataType>
void PrintData(DataType *X)
{
    for (DataType Data : X)
    {
        cout << Data << "\t";
    }
    cout << endl;
}

int main()
{

    int nArray[7] = { 7, 5, 4, 3, 9, 8, 6 };
    double dArray[5] = { 4.3, 2.5, -0.9, 100.2, 3.0 };

    PrintData(nArray);
    PrintData(dArray);

    system("pause");
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

I get an error that **variable Data is undeclared** in the templated function PrintData.

```
error C2065: 'Data' : undeclared identifier 
error C3312: no callable 'begin' function found for type 'double *'    
error C3312: no callable 'begin' function found for type 'int *'    
error C3312: no callable 'end' function found for type 'double *'    
error C3312: no callable 'end' function found for type 'int *'
```

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: I'm positive you got more errors than just the one you mentioned.

Comment: `DataType*` is not an array or container type, a range for loop can't work over it. More fundamentally, `PrintData` as written doesn't know the number of elements that `X` points to. If you want to go down this path, make it `template <typename DataType, size_t N> void PrintData(DataType (&X)[N]) { ... }`. [Demo](http://rextester.com/XYYXJF94394)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have an other doubt. How is that the following code in the main() function work,
for(auto Data : nArray)
{
cout << Data << endl;

Comment: @Igor, the suggestion you gave is correct. Can u explain a little more in detail about the function signature

Comment: @Barry See [Range-based for loop](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for).

Comment: `nArray` in `main` is of array type - specifically `int[7]`, an array of 7 `int`s. `X` in your version of `PrintData` is merely a pointer; the size information is lost. `X` in my version is a reference to an array `T[N]` (`T` and `N` are deduced from the call).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you have included the `iostream` header file and the `using namespace std;` directive. Then your problems are:

1. You should not use `DataType *`. Your code makes `X` a pointer, which is different from array. Use `DataType const&` or `DataType&&` instead.
2. You have to include the `iterator` header file which provides the `begin` and `end` function for C-style array.

The following code works for me.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
using namespace std;

template<typename DataType>
void PrintData(DataType const& X)
{
    for (auto Data : X)
    {
        cout << Data << "\t";
    }
    cout << endl;
}

int main()
{

    int nArray[7] = { 7, 5, 4, 3, 9, 8, 6 };
    double dArray[5] = { 4.3, 2.5, -0.9, 100.2, 3.0 };

    PrintData(nArray);
    PrintData(dArray);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

As commented by Igor Tandetnik, you may use `template<struct DataType, size_t N>` if you want to refer the size of the array.

Update:

1. With `template<struct DataType>` and `DataType *X`, `DataType` is deduced as `int` and `double`, and `X` is a pointer which is not a container.
2. With `template<struct DataType, size_t N>` and `DataType (&X)[N]`, `DataType` is deduced as `int` and `double`, and `X` is an array which can be used with range-based for loop.
3. With `template<struct DataType>` and `DataType&& X` or `DataType const& X`, `DataType` is deduced as `int[7]` or `double[5]`, and `X` is an array as well.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. But i still do not understand the DataTpye (&X)[N]  Signature...

Comment: Let `Type` be some type, then `Type &X` declare a reference right? In this case, `Type` is just replaced by `DataType[N]`. Recall how you  declare a pointer to array. But note that you cannot do this: `typedef DataType (&Type)[N]` because C-style array will be converted to pointer in many cases. If you want to known why, please have a search around.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you're passing the name of the array (e.g., `nArray`), which is just a pointer to the first element, basically. However, new-style `for` loops expect something on which you can call `begin` and `end` - a range.

The following changes make it work by using a `vector` instead of an array. Note that there are very few differences otherwise, and, in general, very few reason to use C-style arrays in contemporary C++.

```
#include <iostream>                                                                                                                                                                                          
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

template<typename DataType>
void PrintData(const DataType &X)
{
    for (const auto &Data : X)
    {
        cout << Data << "\t";
    }
    cout << endl;
}

int main()
{

    vector<int> nArray = { 7, 5, 4, 3, 9, 8, 6 };
    vector<double> dArray = { 4.3, 2.5, -0.9, 100.2, 3.0 };

    PrintData(nArray);
    PrintData(dArray);

    system("pause");
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
```

Comment: I appreciate your answer, I will use containers like vectors next time.

Answer (score 1):

You have some problems:

1) DataType must be a container. So, try to use:

```
std::vector<int> nArray = { 7, 5, 4, 3, 9, 8, 6 };
std::vector<double> dArray = { 4.3, 2.5, -0.9, 100.2, 3.0 };
```

2) You are not going to change the container. It's better to pass container by const reference:

```
template<typename DataType>
void PrintData(const DataType & X);
```

3) Change the loop like this:

```
for (const auto & value : X) {
    std::cout << value << "\t";
}
```

Code example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

template<typename DataType>
void PrintData(const DataType & X) {
    for (const auto & value : X) {
        std::cout << value << "\t";
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
}

int main() {
    std::vector<int> nArray = { 7, 5, 4, 3, 9, 8, 6 };
    std::vector<double> dArray = { 4.3, 2.5, -0.9, 100.2, 3.0 };
    PrintData(nArray);
    PrintData(dArray);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As Igor suggested, If at all you wish to use `DataType *` then you need to do something like this

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
using namespace std;

template <typename DataType, size_t N> 
void PrintData(DataType (&X)[N])
{
    for (auto i : X)
        cout << i << "\t";

    cout << endl;
}

int main()
{    
    int nArray[7] = { 7, 5, 4, 3, 9, 8, 6 };
    double dArray[5] = { 4.3, 2.5, -0.9, 100.2, 3.0 };

    PrintData(nArray);
    PrintData(dArray);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

**Output**

```
7   5   4   3   9   8   6   
4.3 2.5 -0.9    100.2   3
```

---

**Explanation:**

If you see `void PrintData(int* nArray);` & `void PrintData(int (&nArray)[7] );`
are similar declarations, except that seconds one tells where array ends.

Template function

```
template <typename DataType, size_t N> 
void PrintData(DataType (&X)[N])
```

is deduced as'

```
void PrintData(int (&nArray)[7] )
```

You could also write

```
void PrintData(int (&nArray)[7] )
{
    for (auto i : nArray)
        cout << i << "\t";

    cout << endl;
}
```